# How to use JabRef for automatic citing in Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, citing, overleaf, jabref

When using JabRef for texStudio, it gives option for pushing citation (see attached picture). [image: pushing Citation]

How to use same method for citation for overleaf using Jabref. There is no option for pushing citation on overleaf in Jabref

Answer (score 4):

Not possible at the moment (an issue has been filled, but put on hold because of lack of resources --- https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/156.

Temporary solution: use the keyboard shortcut CTRL + K to copy \cite{citationkey), and then paste it in overleaf.

Comment: There is also a PR which provides already basic connection to overleaf. Still requires some work on the Synchronization https://github.com/koppor/jabref/pulls

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround using Dropbox, if you are on an Overleaf Premium Plan.

1. Setup [Dropbox Synchronization](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Dropbox_Synchronization) at Overleaf and synchronize the files to your local PC.
2. Open your local, synchronized `.bib` file with JabRef.
3. Whenever you save in JabRef, it will be uploaded to Dropbox and sent to Overleaf from there. It takes a few seconds, but happens automatically.

If you use this workaround, you should not edit the `.bib` file in Overleaf while JabRef is running. This would result in version conflicts.